# How does length contraction affect collisions at extremely high relative velocities?

Tags: special-relativity

To an observer traveling towards the Earth at a relative velocity close to c, the Earth will be thinner than it would be to a stationary observer, due to length contraction.

What happens as the relative velocity gets so close to the speed of light that the Earth appears thinner than an atom? Thinner than an attometer? Do objects still collide as normal at such high relative velocities, or do they interact differently, or would they pass right through each other?

Similarly, if two electrons approach, does their interaction change if their electric fields are "flattened" due to length contraction, instead of spherical?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/526028/123208

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2011-12-physicists-ultrahigh-energy-proton-black-disk.html